# Horrible battery life with Ubuntu 14.04 on ThinkPad

Tags: 14.04, power-management, lenovo, battery, thinkpad

I've purchased a Lenovo ThinkPad S540, which has according to Lenovo '9 hours of battery life'. I was really happy when I tested the device running Windows 8.1, and the battery worked for 6 hours. But as soon as I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it, the battery got a maximum of 2,5 hours. Why is the battery life so bad with Ubuntu 14.04? I've tried TLP, and other battery-saving tools already but they did not work at all. Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the tool `powertop`. Helped me doubling the battery life on my E530.

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: Just install it, it should manage your battery by itself. If something does not work, run the tool as root to switch power saving mode on and off for specific hardware.

Comment: I had to run --calibrate several times until it let me run --auto-tune without errors (it kept complaining about not enough calibrations made with battery only).